# AS3 fullscreen doesn't work even with button click and allowfullscreen

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to simply add fullscreen capability to my flash movie.
I created a button on the stage (root > setfullscreen) and added that code on root:

```
var isfullscreen=false;
setfullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SetFullscreen); 
function SetFullscreen(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    if (isfullscreen)
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    else
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    isfullscreen=!isfullscreen;

    trace(isfullscreen);
}
```

And I load the swf like that:

```
<OBJECT classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000'
                        codebase='http://macromedia.com/cabs/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0'
                        ID=flaMovie>
<PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE='movie.swf'>
<PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high">
<PARAM NAME="allowfullscreen" VALUE="true">
<EMBED src='movie.swf' 
                        style='width:800px;height:560px' 
                        TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

I don't find anything else to do, but it doesn't work, nothing happen when clicking the button, just the trace which switch from true to false when testing the movie in flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add the allowFullScreen to the embed tag as well:

```
<embed src="movie.swf" allowFullScreen="true">
```